# UNIX evaluate expression from a variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have a variable which has a math expression. I want to evaluate it in UNIX shell and store the result in another variable. how do i do that ?

i tried the following but it doesn't works

```
var1="3+1"
var2=`expr "$var1"`
echo $var2
```

the var2 value should be calculated as 4.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it this way

```
var2=$(($var1))
```

Answer (score 6):

`expr` requires spaces between operands and operators. Also, you need backquotes to capture the output of a command. The following would work:

```
var1="3 + 1"
var2=`expr $var1`
echo $var2
```

If you want to evaluate arbitrary expressions (beyond the limited syntax supported by `expr`) you could use `bc`:

```
var1="3+1"
var2=`echo $var1 | bc`
echo $var2
```

Comment: Please don't use backticks in shell scripts, whenever possible.  Use command-substitution `$()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
eval "var2=\$(( $var1 ))"
```

Using built-in shell arithmetic avoids some complexity and `expr`'s limited parser.

Answer (score 1):

Try with backticks:

```
var2=`expr $var1`
```

Edit: you'll need to include spaces in your equation for expr to work.

Comment: yes, I had missed the part where he didn't include spaces.  And I'm guessing he did have the backticks and they just got eaten because he didn't quote the code, so I'll give Andrew a plus one for beating me to the right answer.

Comment: Please don't use backticks in shell scripts.  It's almost always better to use command-substitution `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
var1="3+1"
var2=$((var1))
echo $var2
```

#### output is: 4

Answer (score 0):

If these are mathematical expressions:

```
var2=$( bc <<< "$var1" )
```

or, for older shells

```
var2=$( printf "%s\n" "$var1" | bc )
```